# Generation Of Signed CSR Using Bouncy Castle With PKCS11 Library

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I'm trying to generating a Signed CSR Using Bouncy Castle fips library with a private key present in USB token.

Currently bouncy castle is not providing a option to attach the signature bytes(generated using USB token) to pkcs10certificationRequest.

how can i achieve this using bouncy castle library.??

I'm using a PKCS10CertificationRequest object to generate a Signed CSR, which is expecting ContentSigner object as a input, so i created my own contentsigner by implementing the methods
1. getSignature().
2. getoutputstream().
3. getalgorithmidentifier().

Where getsignature function is invoking the PKCS11 library calls to generate a signature using x500Name and public key as a input and signing the input data using private key present in token.

using this flow i can generate a signed CSR, but when i tried to validate the generated signed CSR using isvalid() function its throwing an error "Invalid Signature"

Using following code for generating signed CSR Using bouncy castle with PKCS11 library:

where

```
publicKeyInfo is a public key retrieved from usb token. 
signingPrivKey is a handle for the private key present in usb token.

CertificationRequestInfo certificateRequestInfo = new CertificationRequestInfo(subject, publicKeyInfo, new DERSet());
    ContentSigner contentSigner = new ContentSigner() {

        @Override
        public byte[] getSignature()
        {
            try 
            {
                PrivateKey signingPrivKey = null;
                RSAPrivateKey templateForSignKey = new RSAPrivateKey();
                templateForSignKey.getId().setByteArrayValue(id);
                session.findObjectsInit(templateForSignKey);
                Object[] privKeyObjects = session.findObjects(1);
                if (privKeyObjects.length > 0)
                {
                    signingPrivKey = (PrivateKey) privKeyObjects[0];
                }
                session.findObjectsFinal();

                ByteArrayInputStream dataInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateRequestInfo.getEncoded());
                MessageDigest digestEngine = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256", "BCFIPS");
                Mechanism signatureMechanism = Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_RSA_PKCS);
                //Initialize for signing
                session.signInit(signatureMechanism, signingPrivKey);

                byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                // feed all data from the input stream to the message digest
                while ((bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(dataBuffer)) >= 0)
                {
                    digestEngine.update(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                byte[] digest = digestEngine.digest();
                byte[] signatureValue = session.sign(digest);
                return signatureValue;
            }
            catch (TokenException e)
            {
                setMsg(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {
                setMsg(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                setMsg(e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                setMsg(e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream getOutputStream()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier()
        {
            AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(hashingAlgo);
            return algorithmIdentifier;
        }
    };

    AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmId = contentSigner.getAlgorithmIdentifier();
    byte[] signData = contentSigner.getSignature();
    DERBitString derBitStr = new DERBitString(signData);

    CertificationRequest certReq = new CertificationRequest(certificateRequestInfo, algorithmId, derBitStr);
    PKCS10CertificationRequest pkcs10Req = new PKCS10CertificationRequest(certReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of brainstorming at last achieved to generate perfect signed CSR using Bouncy castle FIPS, PKCS11 library.

The changes in the above code is that, we have to wrap the message digest bytes data in MessageDigestInfo object and send the encoded data from MessageDigestInfo to PKCS11 Sign Function.